# Telegram webhook: Why i get ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed Error when i call GetWebhookInfo API command?

Tags: ssl, openssl, telegram, telegram-bot

```
Server: Win Server 2012
Web server: IIS 8.5
Project: Asp.Net MVC
```

I *bought* a **wildcard SSL certification** for my domain and its subdomains and installed it on my server and bound to the website (in IIS).

It show green secure HTTPS in browser.

[image]

I used Telegram **`SetWebhook`** with my webhook URL (Something like this: `https://webhook.example.com/api/WebhookAction/`)

But when i run Telegram **`GetWebhookInfo`** it return `certificate verify failed` error:

```
{  
   "ok":true,
   "result":{  
      "url":"https://webhook.example.com/api/WebhookAction/",
      "has_custom_certificate":false,
      "pending_update_count":1,
      "last_error_date":1489066503,
      "last_error_message":"SSL error {336134278, error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}",
      "max_connections":40
   }
}
```

**What do you think about this problem?**

- Should i change the Webhook Url to a *None-SubDomain address* like this: `https://mydomain:8443/api/WebhookAction` ?
- Has my `SSL` any problem (for example should be a *None-Wildcard SSL*)?

---

**Edit**

Also i tried:

### Self-Signed Certificate way

**A)**
I Created a **Self Signed Certificate** by the following `OpenSSL` command instead of the Wildcard SSL

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout MyDomain_private_key.key -x509 -days 365 -out MyDomain_public.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=MyDomain/O=MyDomain/CN=webhook.example.com"
```

**B)**
Then i created a `PFX` from the output files by this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out MyDomain.pfx -inkey MyDomain_private.key -in MyDomain_public.pem -certfile MyDomain_public.pem
```

**C)**
Then i installed the `MyDomain.pfx` on the server and bind it to the `Https://webhook.mydomain.com`.

[image]

**D)**
Also i used the `MyDomain_public.pem` file in the `SetWebhook` command as the certification file (with both a third library and `Curl` command).

The `Curl` command:

```
curl -F "url=https://webhook.example.com/api/Webhookaction/" -F "certificate=C:\path\mydomain_public.pem" https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/setWebhook
```

**But** when i call `GetWebhookInfo` API command, it return this error:

```
{  
   "ok":true,
   "result":{  
      "url":"https://api.telegram.org/bot[token]/setWebhook?url=https://webhook.mydomain.com/api/webhookaction/",
      "has_custom_certificate":true,
      "pending_update_count":1,
      "last_error_date":1489126755,
      "last_error_message":"SSL error {336134278, error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}",
      "max_connections":40
   }
}
```

**What is my mistake?**

Comment: There is an easier way to do this self-signing. Please create a new question on this topic, so it is clearer for other SO users

Comment: OK @CharlesOkwuagwu, i wrote another question about how to create a Self-Signed Certificate to use for telegram webhook and i will put its link here for you soon. Thank you.

Comment: Please can you give a link to the new question

Comment: Thank you @CharlesOkwuagwu . The new question link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713926/what-is-easy-way-to-create-a-use-an-self-signed-certification-for-a-telegram-web

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Fix your certificate. ***`CN=example.com`*** is probably wrong. Hostnames always go in the *SAN*. If its present in the *CN*, then it must be present in the *SAN* too (you have to list it twice in this case). For more rules and reasons, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to use wild card certificates.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#the-short-version

1. Provides a supported, **non-wildcard**, verified or self-signed certificate.
2. Uses a CN or SAN that matches the domain you’ve supplied on setup.
3. Supplies all intermediate certificates to complete a verification chain.

Comment: Thank you Charles, I tried to create and use a self-signed certificate, i write some description about the steps and added to the question. May you help me? Why i get error too? What is my mistake?

Comment: @RAM were you able to use the self signed?

Comment: My way to using the pfx file is similar to this topic: `https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-7.html` then i use Add Site Binding in IIS to bing it to the subdomain.

Comment: `Supplies all intermediate certificates to complete a verification chain.` can you tell me how to do this in apache?

Answer (score 0):

The error in your getWebHookInfo:

```
"last_error_message":"SSL error {337047686, error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}"
```

Is Telegram saying that it needs the whole certificate chain (it's also called CA Bundle or full chained certificate).

#### How to check your certificate:

You can use the SSL Labs [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) service to check your certificate:

Just pass your URL like the following example, replacing `coderade.github.io` with your host:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=coderade.github.io&hideResults=on&latest

If you see **"Chain issues: Incomplete"** you do not serve full chained certificate.

#### How to fix that:

Download the full chained certificate for your SSL certificate provider and install this on your webserver.

I don't know which service you are using, but for my example, with [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) I solved adding the [ca-certs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#ca-certs) with `ca-bundle` file sent by my SSL Certificate provider (In my case [Namecheap Comodo](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo/positivessl.aspx)) on my SSL configuration, like the following example:

```
ca_certs = "cert/my-service.ca-bundle"
```

For further information: [@martini](https://github.com/zammad/zammad/issues/770#issuecomment-310484775) answer on this [thread](https://github.com/zammad/zammad/issues/770) and the [FIX: Telegram Webhooks Not Working](https://www.cubewebsites.com/blog/guides/fix-telegram-webhooks-not-working/) site.