# What is easy way to create and use a Self-Signed Certification for a Telegram Webhook?

Tags: ssl, webhooks, telegram, self-signed

**System info:**

```
Server Win Server 2012
Web Server: IIS 8.5
Project platform: ASP.NET MVC
Webhook Path: https://webhook.MYDOMAIN.com/api/webhookaction

// I use my domain name instead of MYDOMAIN
```

I used the following way to create a **Self-Signed Certification** to use for a **Telegram Webhook** but finally telegram return SSL error to me, **do you know an easier way to success?**

---

**A)**
I Created a **Self Signed Certificate** by the following `OpenSSL` command instead of the Wildcard SSL

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout MyDomain_private_key.key -x509 -days 365 -out MyDomain_public.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=MyDomain/O=MyDomain/CN=webhook.MyDomain.com"
```

**B)**
Then i created a `PFX` from the output files by this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out MyDomain.pfx -inkey MyDomain_private.key -in MyDomain_public.pem -certfile MyDomain_public.pem
```

**C)**
Then i installed the `MyDomain.pfx` on the server and bind it to the `Https://webhook.mydomain.com`.

[image]

**D)**
Also i used the `MyDomain_public.pem` file in the `SetWebhook` command as the certification file (with both a third library and `Curl` command).

The `Curl` command:

```
curl -F "url=https://webhook.MyDomain.com/api/Webhookaction/" -F "certificate=C:\path\mydomain_public.pem" https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/setWebhook
```

**But** when i call `GetWebhookInfo` API command, it return this error:

```
{  
   "ok":true,
   "result":{  
      "url":"https://api.telegram.org/bot[token]/setWebhook?url=https://webhook.mydomain.com/api/webhookaction/",
      "has_custom_certificate":true,
      "pending_update_count":1,
      "last_error_date":1489126755,
      "last_error_message":"SSL error {336134278, error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}",
      "max_connections":40
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this quick and easy method of setting up self-signed webhooks for Telegram (on Windows, but it should work for other OS too)

1. create your certificates using openSSL

   openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout PRIVATE.key -x509 -days 365 -out PUBLIC.pem -subj "/C=NG/ST=Lagos/L=Lagos/O=YOUR_NAME_OR_COMPANY_NAME/CN=SERVER_NAME_OR_IP"
2. Next setup the webhook on telegram using this easy method:

[How to set Telegram bot webhook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554548/how-to-set-telegram-bot-webhook/42556264#42556264) you should get a result like this:

```
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}
```

3. check that the webhook is properly setup on Telegram:
   https://api.telegram.org/bot[token]/getWebhookinfo

`{
ok: true,
result: {
         url: "[SERVER_NAME_OR_IP]:[PORT]/[YOUR_BOT_TOKEN]",
         has_custom_certificate: true,
         pending_update_count: 0,
         max_connections: 30
      }
}`

4. you can test your ssl setup [here](https://www.wormly.com/test_ssl)  and [here](https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/)
5. I personally ***don't use IIS*** for my bots. I use a very light weight web-server (elli) as part of my bot server built in Elixir, the certificate setup for that server is as simple as pointing to the path of the public and private keys in a config file.
6. For IIS [this will direct you](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/10/27/configure-iis-to-use-your-self-signed-certificates-with-your-application/)

Comment: Thank you, i will test it and get back to you soon.

Comment: Dear @Charles, Thanks a lot, i used my domain with a port and your script to SetWebhook, finally it worked very well :). Also I have a question: Do you know dose it work with a subdomain without port (e.g. `webhook.mydomain.com`) instead of the domain with port (e.g. `mydomain.com:8443`)

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Since it is https, by default the port is 443, so when you setWebhook you could also specify port 443